# infinite loop after scrolling to bottom of page window scroll react

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener, next.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollpos);
}

scrollpos=()=>{
    console.log(window.scrollY);

    if(window.scrollY > 500){
        this.setState({
            navfix:'navfix'
        })
    }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollpos);
}
```

Hi I'm using this approach to get window scroll position but when I scroll to  bottom of the page or in my case > 1800 of scroll position, I got infinite loop number scroll position. Why this happen?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Do u have componentDidUpdate or other lifeCycle method in your component? there is nothing wrong from your current snippet code.

Please provide the whole component so we can understand the flow.

Comment: hmm i think i found the problem , im using owlcarousel in my component then this happn when i remove owlcarousel its fine

Comment: glad to hear you found the problem! :)